# How to test a Bootstrap linked glyph in spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to find a clean way to write a view test in Rspec that contains the following elements:

```
<a href="/things/2/widgets">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt inline"></span>
</a>
```

What I'd like to do is test that when the page is rendered in the view test that 'glyphicon-share-alt' links to the `widgets_things_path`

Any thoughts on how you'd do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use have_css to check a specific anchor, and then to check a specific tag within it:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Model, type: :feature do
  before { visit some_path }
  let(:anchor) { 'a[href="url"]' }

  it 'has an anchor with specific url' do
    expect(page).to have_css anchor
  end

  it 'has a specific span inside anchor' do
    expect(page).to have_css "#{anchor} > span.glyphicon.glyphicon-share-alt.inline"
  end
end
```